# Lenovo touchpad is unstable in Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, lenovo, cursor, mouse-pointer

My Lenovo IdeaPad 320 touchpad is unstable; it jumps very often like the sensitive was high. I already set the sensitivity to the minimum value but the instability continues.

```
renan@renan-cunha-laptop:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ xinput --list`

⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3336-001                      id=9    [slave pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ Logitech G400s Optical Gaming Mouse       id=12   [slave pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3   [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ EasyCamera: EasyCamera                    id=8    [slave keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=10   [slave keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave keyboard (3)]  

renan@renan-cunha-laptop:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ ls

10-amdgpu.conf  10-radeon.conf    51-synaptics-quirks.conf  70-wacom.conf
10-quirks.conf  40-libinput.conf  70-synaptics.conf
```

Comment: Did you install from scratch, or upgrade in place from an earlier version?

Comment: Please add output of `xinput list-props 9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package:

```bsh
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

This appears to have mitigated the erratic/jumpy Synaptics TM3336-002 touch-pad on my Lenovo V130. Now, even if my finger actually skips a bit across the surface, the motion of the cursor is still perfectly fluid.